# %timeit equivalent in code

Tags: python, timing

The magic command `%timeit` is great to measure code execution times in an interactive way. However, I want to get the result of `%timeit` in order to plot the results. `timeit.timeit` allows this as well, but does not have the automatic scaling of the number of iterations and the normalising of the result that `%timeit` has.

Is there a built in function that can time a piece of code, which also automatically adjusts the number of iterations it performs, and returns a normalised result?

Comment: I think there is not, but for timing you can just create a timer decorator, the iteration counter is not so easy to make it work as you would like.

Comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/acb2c91c5522bf1c0cb1c06c1882044a08cdf09b/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L902 - though probably not usable from a user perspective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The magic [`%timeit`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) command offers a `-o` option:

> -o: return a [TimeitResult](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html#IPython.core.magics.execution.TimeitResult) that can be stored in a variable to inspect the result in more details.

It will still print the result but also return the result so that it can be captured in a variable. The syntax for magic commands is a bit limited but you could collect different results in a `list` by assigning it to a variable and appending that variable to a list:

```
res = []
for i in range(3):
    a = %timeit -o 10*10
    res.append(a)
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 61 ns per loop
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 61.1 ns per loop
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 60.8 ns per loop
```

and then access `res`:

```
print(res)
# [<TimeitResult : 10000000 loops, best of 3: 61.2 ns per loop>,
#  <TimeitResult : 10000000 loops, best of 3: 61.3 ns per loop>,
#  <TimeitResult : 10000000 loops, best of 3: 61.5 ns per loop>]
```

Each of these results has several attributes, which might be of interest:

```
print(res[0].all_runs)
# [0.6166532894762563, 0.6102780388983005, 0.6370787790842183]
print(res[0].best)
# 6.102780388983005e-08
print(res[0].compile_time)
# 0.00020554513866197934
print(res[0].loops)
# 10000000
print(res[0].repeat)
# 3
print(res[0].worst)
# 1.1170931449020795e-06
```

To plot for example the best times you need to create a new list containing the best values:

```
res_best_times = [result.best * 1e9 for result in res] 
# "* 1e9" to get the result in nanoseconds
print(res_best_times)
# [61.2, 61.3, 61.5]
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you can use/import IPython, and you simply want to create a headless script that uses the `%timeit` magic, you could do something like the following.

Assume the following is in the file testme.py:

```
from IPython import get_ipython

def myfun(x):
    return x**x

val = 12.3
out = get_ipython().run_line_magic("timeit","-o myfun({})".format(val))

#do something with out, which will be a TimeitResult object
```

Then you can run the script non-interactively with:

```
ipython testme.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Using cell magic %%

In:

```
%%timeit -o
res = []
for i in range(5):
    a = 10*10
    res.append(a)
```

Out:

```
526 ns ± 44.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
<TimeitResult : 526 ns ± 44.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)>
```

The variable underscore '_' stores the last expression value

In:

```
result = _
result
```

Out:

```
<TimeitResult : 526 ns ± 44.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)>
```

And now we can get more data from attributes (`help(result)`)

In:

```
print(result.average)  # 2.358365715216288e-06
print(result.stdev)  # 5.159462070683934e-07
print(result.timings)  #[3.5457100011626608e-06, ..., 2.4937099988164847e-06]
print(result.all_runs)  # [0.0003545710001162661, ... 0.00024937099988164846]
print(result.best)  # 2.003900021442676e-06
print(result.compile_time)  # 0.00030000000000995897
print(result.loops)  # 100
print(result.repeat)  # 7
print(result.worst)  # 3.5457100011626608e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

I used timing functions to compare the different methods.

All of the functions were tested on this nested list:

```py
nested_array = [[[[]]], [], [[[[1], [2, 3], [4, [5, [6, [7, [8]]]]]]]], [[], [], [[1], [2, 3], [4, [5, [6, [7, [8]]]]]]], [[1], [2, 3], [4, [5, [6, [7, [8]]]]]]]
```

and they all return

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

From the fastest to the slowest, we have:

### Leaderboard

#### 1st

I created this one, and was not expecting to see in in #1. It features the `extend` method which is underrated.

```py
from typing import Any

def flatten_for_loop(value: list[list, Any]) -> list[Any]:
    flat = []

    for i in value:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            flat.extend(flatten_for_loop(i))
        else:
            flat.append(i)

    return flat
```

```
%%timeit
flatten_for_loop(nested_array)
>>> 4.58 µs ± 83.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

#### 2nd

this one is very elegant and has `yield from` statement which is interesting and that we do not see very often.

```py
from typing import Any, Iterator

def flatten_generator(xs: list[list, Any]) -> Iterator[Any]:
    for x in xs:
        if isinstance(x, list) and not isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten_generator(x)
        else:
            yield x
```

```
%%timeit
list(flatten_generator(nested_array))
>>> 7.07 µs ± 17.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

#### 3rd

```py
from typing import Any

def flatten_list_comprehension(x: list[list, Any]) -> list[Any]:
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [a for i in x for a in flatten_list_comprehension(i)]
    else:
        return [x]
```

```
%%timeit
flatten_list_comprehension(nested_array)
>>> 8.67 µs ± 59.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

#### 4th

this function creates a lot of copies (list_[:] creates a shallow copy of list_)

```py
from typing import Any

def flatten_1(value: list[list, Any]) -> list[Any]:
    if value == []:
        return value
    if isinstance(value[0], list):
        return flatten_1(value[0]) + flatten_1(value[1:])
    return value[:1] + flatten_1(value[1:])
```

```
%%timeit
flatten_1(nested_array)
>>> 9.69 µs ± 55.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

#### 5th

```py
from typing import Any

import pandas as pd

def flatten_pandas_core(value: list[list, Any]) -> list[Any]:
    return list(pandas.core.common.flatten(value))
```

```
%%timeit
flatten_pandas_core(nested_array)
>>> 13.5 µs ± 91.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```